# Set Default value for dropdown in Quick Edit view - Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am on a SharePoint list view and click on edit this list option . It opens in quick edit mode, there we can also create new records.

Here I want to have one field to be auto selected. that is a lookup field. Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible with SharePoint Standard functionality. I currently have the same challenge, and I'm going to implement this by myself via JavaScript.

Edit: I implemented it. Although it's not easy, a good explanation and example can be found here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/813090/Master-detail-with-JSGrid

Basically the solution is to hook up into JSGrid default events and set properties by script. The good thing is that this works even if the column that is updated is not displayed at all.